# Why you can put php.ini variables into .htaccess?

Tags: apache, .htaccess, config, php

As in the topic - why you can put them in .htaccess.

I always thought that it should be in php.ini not in .htaccess.

.htaccess

```
php_value max_execution_time 240
php_value max_input_time 111
```

php.ini

```
max_execution_time 240
max_input_time 111
```

Why it can be like that?

Comment: Because... you can.

Comment: Read the docs ... http://php.net/manual/en/configuration.changes.php  perfectly legal ...

Comment: "Why..." questions do not usually have definitive answers. Are you asking for use cases?

Comment: .htaccess allows per-directory overrides, so you can have different configurations in multiple directories.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

People on shared web hosts often won't have access to the php.ini file, so it's convenient to be able to override certain PHP settings in the .htaccess file (if you really need to).

Comment: Thanks, I've always been able to create php.ini file on my hosting :D

Answer (score 1):

In some cases, you want to override a specific php configuration just at one part of your application, and not for the whole server. That .htaccess approach solves that problem.

For instance, you have 4 completely different applications running on a single remote server. Each application defines specific php configurations in their own .htaccess files.

*edit: also what @pjumble correctly said.